# Angular 9 type checking in a function returns "object"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this method that I have bound to a component output handler like this:

```
<app-favorite [favorites]="screenshot.favorites" [userId]="userId" (save)="updateFavorites(screenshot)">
</app-favorite>
```

The problem here is the **screenshot** can actually be a `Screenshot` or a `Video`, so I am trying to do a type check to handle it.

In my method I have this:

```
updateFavorites(model: Screenshot | Video): void {
  console.log(model instanceof Screenshot);
  var t = new Screenshot();
  console.log(t instanceof Screenshot);

  /// ****** removed for brevity ****** ///
}
```

The first console log outputs **false** and the second is **true**.
When I add these console logs:

```
console.log(model instanceof Screenshot);
console.log(model.constructor.name);
var t = new Screenshot();
console.log(t instanceof Screenshot);
console.log(t.constructor.name);
```

It outputs:

> false
>
> object
>
> true
>
> Screenshot

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you aslo show the part from `app-favourite` comp from where you emit the data?

Comment: Can you show us where `screenshot` is defined?

Comment: If you notice, it doesn't get the screenshot passed to the app-favorite, just the favorites. The `save` emit only emits a boolean

Comment: screenshot is defined at the top of the component like this: `@Input() screenshots: Screenshot[] | Video[];`

Comment: then whomever pass `screenshots`, they pass something else than `Screenshot[] | Video[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround for type assertion would be to utilize a type guard using type predicate. Try the following

```js
private isScreenshot(model: Screenshot | Video): model is Screenshot {
  return (model as Screenshot).<property> !== undefined;
}
```

You need to replace the `<property>` placeholder with a property specific to the `Screenshot` class. Then you could assert the type in runtime using the following

```js
updateFavorites(model: Screenshot | Video): void {
  if (this.isScreenshot(model)) {
    // do something with object of type `Screenshot`
  } else {
    // do something with object of type `Video`
  }
}
```